# Ошибка в функции поиска минимального элемента массива

Tags: c

В функции array_min каким то образом получается sizeof(a) = 4, хотя подобной проблемы в array_max не возникает. Из-за этого функция работает неправильно.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array_max(int *a);
int array_min(int *a);

void main()
{
    int max, min;
    int a[3] = {-23, -24, -7};

    max = array_max(a);
    min = array_min(a);

    printf("max=%d\nmin=%d\n", max, min);
}

int array_max(int *a)
{
    int i, max = 0, flag = 0;
    for( i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++ )
    {
        if( a[i] > max || flag == 0 )
        {
            max = a[i];
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    return max;
}

int array_min(int *a)
{
    int i, min = 0, flag = 0;
    for( i=0; i<sizeof(a); i++ )
    {
        if( a[i] < min || flag == 0 )
        {
            min = a[i];
            flag = 1;
        }
    }

    return min;
}
```

[Пример работы на ideone.com для массива с тремя элементами](http://ideone.com/4VYVai)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего вы ошибаетесь - **sizeof(a)** будет иметь результат, равный 4 как в Функции **array_min**, так и в функции **array_max**, проверьте внимательнее.

Но основная ваша ошибка не в этом. А вот в чем: вы судя по всему неправильно понимаете, что делает **sizeof**. Если вы применяете **sizeof** к указателю, то вы получите не количество элементов в массиве, а всего лишь размер указателя.  А он обычно равен 4 байтам. В Си вообще нет способа проверки длины массива "из коробки". Для этого вам  либо нужно использовать использовать всяческие хитрые трюки вплоть до замены массивов на пользовательские типы данных, либо просто передавать в функцию дополнительный параметр, содержащий длину массива

Answer (score 2):

А в чём вы видите проблему? `sizeof(a)` и правда равно 4, т. к. `a` — указатель, размер = 4 байта.

Вы должны передавать размер массива в функции `array_min` и `array_max` как дополнительный аргумент. Это нормальная практика для языка C. Sorry for that.

В других языках идиоматичные контейнеры могут ответить на вопрос о своём размере за счёт внутренних дополнительных данным. Но C — язык низкоуровневый, близкий к железу. В нём за передачу дополнительной информации отвечает сам программист, массив — лишь кусок памяти с данными.

Answer (score 0):

Жутко корявый, неидеоматичный код. Советую переписать вот так:

```
int array_min(int* arr, size_t siz)
{
    int min = *arr;
    while( --siz ) {
        if( *++arr < min ) {
            min = *arr;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```